# MySQL Month and Year grouping slow performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I've got a report which I need to show the month and year profit from my transaction the query which I made and works is very slow and can not figure out how I can manage to change the query the way that consumes less time to load.

```
SELECT MONTH(MT4_TRADES.CLOSE_TIME) as MONTH
     , YEAR(MT4_TRADES.CLOSE_TIME) as YEAR
     , SUM(MT4_TRADES.SWAPS) as SWAPS
     , SUM(MT4_TRADES.VOLUME)/100 as VOLUME
     , SUM(MT4_TRADES.PROFIT) AS PROFIT 
  FROM MT4_TRADES 
  JOIN MT4_USERS 
    ON MT4_TRADES.LOGIN = MT4_USERS.LOGIN 
 WHERE MT4_TRADES.CMD < 2  
   AND MT4_TRADES.CLOSE_TIME <> "1970-01-01 00:00:00" 
   AND MT4_USERS.AGENT_ACCOUNT <> "1" 
 GROUP 
    BY YEAR(MT4_TRADES.CLOSE_TIME)
     , MONTH(MT4_TRADES.CLOSE_TIME) 
 ORDER 
    BY YEAR
```

This is the full query, any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

This is the result of explain:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an index on `CLOSE_TIME`? It might not help, but it's probably the only thing that could. Also, try referring to the aliases in your `GROUP BY` clause, instead of repeating the expressions.

Comment: Yes I have index on CLOSE_TIME and I tried GROUP BY with Aliases but no change

Comment: @Barmar Would a composite index on some arrangement of (login,cmd,close_time) not help?

Comment: Hard to know. Post the result of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Betcha they don't.

Comment: I always refer to http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql for indexing issues. I haven't looked through it in a while so I can't specifically point to a section for you, but reading this through should give you insight into how to build an index for this query.

Comment: In this case, building and maintaining a [Summary table](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) will be much more productive than trying to fix the indexing.

Comment: @Barmer I just updated the question with explain results.

Comment: EXPLAIN output is showing a full scan of the MTR_TRADES table; MySQL did consider, using an index (three possible indexes) but the estimated cost of the full scan was lower. The big rock is that "Using filesort" operation on several thousand rows.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing the comment from @Barmar,  look at the `EXPLAIN` output to see query execution plan. Verify that suitable indexes are being used.

Likely the big rock in terms of performance is the "Using filesort" operation.

To get around that, we would need a suitable index available. and that would require some changes to the table. (The typical question on "improve query performance" topic on SO comes with a restrictions that we "can't add indexes or make any changes to the table".)

I'd be looking at a functional index (feature added in MySQL 8.0, for MySQL 5.7, I'd be looking at adding generated columns and including generated columns in a secondary index, featured added in MySQL 5.7)

```
CREATE INDEX `MT4_TRADES_ix2` ON MT4_TRADES ((YEAR(close_time)),(MONTH(close_time)))
```

I'd be tempted to go with a covering index, and also change the grouping to a single expression e.g. `DATE_FORMAT(close_time,'%Y-%m')`

```
CREATE INDEX `MT4_TRADES_ix3` ON MT4_TRADES ((DATE_FORMAT(close_time,'%Y-%m'))
  ,swaps,volume,profit,login,cmd,closetime)
```

from the query, it looks like `login` is going to be UNIQUE in `MT4_USERS` table, likely that's the PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE KEY, so an index is going to be available, but we're just guessing...

With suitable indexes available, we could so something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(close_time,'%Y-%m')                                    AS close_year_mo
     , SUM(IF(t.cmd < 2 AND t.close_time <> '1970-01-01', t.swaps  ,NULL))      AS swaps
     , SUM(IF(t.cmd < 2 AND t.close_time <> '1970-01-01', t.volume ,NULL))/100  AS volume
     , SUM(IF(t.cmd < 2 AND t.close_time <> '1970-01-01', t.profit ,NULL))      AS profit 
  FROM MT4_TRADES t
  JOIN MT4_USERS u
    ON u.login = t.login 
   AND u.agent_account <> '1' 
 GROUP BY close_year_mo
 ORDER BY close_year_mo
```

and we'd expect MySQL to do a loose index scan, with the `EXPLAIN` output top show "using index for group-by" and not show "Using filesort"

---

*EDIT*

For versions of MySQL before 5.7, we could create new columns, e.g.`year_close` and `month_close`, populate the columns with the results of expressions  `YEAR(close_time)` and `MONTH(close_time)`  (we could create BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers to handle that automatically for us)

Then we could create index with those columns as the leading columns

```
 CREATE INDEX ...  ON MT4_TRADES ( year_close, month_close, ... )
```

And then reference the new columns in the query

```
SELECT t.year_close  AS `YEAR`
     , t.month_close  AS `MONTH`

  FROM MT4_TRADES t
  JOIN ...
 WHERE ...
 GROUP
    BY t.year_close
     , t.month_close
```

Ideally include in the index all of referenced columns from MT4_TRADES, to make a *covering index* for the query.

Comment: Let me check this @Spencer7593 and will post the result as soonest.

Comment: CREATE INDEX `MT4_TRADES_ix2` ON MT4_TRADES ((YEAR(close_time),MONTH(close_time)) Get SQL Syntax error number #1064

Comment: functional indexes were introduced with MySQL 8.0, not available in earlier versions. (I attempted to note the newness of this feature in the answer, in the fourth paragraphy, the mention of MySQL 5.7+ is erroneous;  MySQL 5.7 added generated columns, and the ability to included generated columns in indexes ...  fourth paragraph of answer edited

Comment: A filesort does make a large impact on database performance and should be actively avoided.

Comment: @Predator: a "Using filesort" operation on a trivial set won't have a big impact; but it totally will with large sets.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on MySQL 8.0.22:
mysql> CREATE INDEX orders_created_at_ix ON orders (YEAR(created_at));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'created_at))' at line 1

Comment: @Pelle  I'm thinking the key_part expression needs to be enclosed in parens, in addition to the parens around the index list e.g. `... ON orders ((YEAR(created_at)))`  compare to the examples in the Reference Manual here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts    (reviewing my answer, it looks like there may be a problem with the parens in a couple of my examples)